# Python inserting a key into a dictionary between 2 other keys

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary in a python script and I need to insert a new key into a very specific place in that dictionary. I know the names of the keys around where I need to insert the new key, but I am a bit puzzled how to do this. My only thought is to add all of the sub-keys to temp dictionaries, drop them from the original dictionary, add what I want and then readd the original keys, but I assume there is an easier way to do this.

```
    original_dict = {
        "California" : {
            "San Diego": 100,
            "Los Angeles": 200,
        }
    }
```

How would I insert the key value ("San Francisco", 150) between SD and LA? Doing

```
   original_dict["California"]["San Francisco"]=150
```

adds the new key to the end which is not where I want it (and neither do the people who are ingesting the file). Google turned up nothing.

Comment: If you want to maintain order (different from insertion order), a dict is the wrong data structure.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I have a dictionary, which I get from an upstream service so I can't change what I have. I could cast it as a string or a json object, the former doesn't seem like it will help me and the latter looks like a dictionary. Is there some other way to manipulate the data that I am not thinking of? I am new enough at this that this could be a knowledge thing, but the world I am working in revolves around dictionaries and so this is what I have to work with.

Comment: How large is this data structure? Like for the example, would "California" typically have 10, 100, 1000 or 10000 entries?

Comment: The California Subkey (the only one I care about) has a fixed number of keys (8, 9 if you count the insertion). Other subkeys are very large and variable, but as I am not touching those that doesn't seem troubling.

Comment: As already commented: dictionary is not a good way. You should distinguish input/output (e.g. to other services) and your internal representation. In your case, I would put a list which will contain dictionary with just one element (or just a tuple). When you export you transform to expected structure. Note: python has orderedDictionaries https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict but doens't provide "insert between"

Comment: Fair enough. It would be great if I had a different structure to work with in, but as I do not control that I will just wrangle the solution I wish to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you can't insert an item in the middle of a dictionary. You will have to create a new sub-dictionary and put it to original dictionary.
For example, a list of tuples can be used:

```py
original_dict = {
    "California" : {
        "San Diego": 100,
        "Los Angeles": 200,
    }
}  
parent_key = "California"
new_item = ("San Francisco", 150)

siblings = list(original_dict[parent_key].items())
siblings.append(new_item)
siblings.sort(key = lambda e: e[1])

original_dict[parent_key] = dict(siblings)

print(original_dict)
```

Output

```
{'California': {'San Diego': 100, 'San Francisco': 150, 'Los Angeles': 200}}
```

Arguably a more efficient solution can be implemented which:

1. Removes (`dict.pop`) the elements starting from an insertion index.
2. Collects them (from step #1).
3. Puts a new item.
4. Puts all collected in step #2.

Comment: Thank you this is as good as I expect to get here.